Probabilistic method, dependencies of triangles based at $x$
In the following notes
the author states, at page $64$, $4$th line of Theorem $8.10$, that
$$
\Delta=\sum_{\left(i,j\right):\ i \sim j}\mathbb{P}\left(B_{i} \wedge B_{j}\right) =
6{n-1 \choose 4}p^{9}
$$

However, I believe this to be wrong, as I obtain
$2\left(n - 3\right){n - 1 \choose 2}p^{5}$.
For whoever is familiar with this passage of the famous book The Probabilistic Method (which the author is referring to, precisely Theorem $8.5.4$), is my counting wrong or the author of the notes is mistaken ?.

Thanks a lot for any help.
EDIT: upon request, I briefly summarise the setup: with reference to the random graph $G(n,p)$, and an enumeration $A_i$ of all the triangles of the complete graph $K_n$ sharing a fixed vertex $x$, the  $B_i$ denotes the event that the triangle $A_i$ is in $G(n,p)$. $\wedge$ denotes the intersection of events. The relationship $i\sim j$ means that $A_i\neq A_j$ and they share one edge.

Questions should be reasonably self contained... it shouldn't be necessary to refer to links and external articles just to learn what the question is.

Just to say, whatever those formulas mean,  the first one vanishes if $n=4$ but the second doesn't. Seems like that should be a bright line indicator.

thank you for the comment, the setup is quite laborious, so since the book is quite famous, it is best to refer to it directly. You are right about  that, $n\ge 3$.

$4$ satisfies $n≥3$.

yes, that is why I said you are right.

I added the setup, hopefully it is not too brief

Your counting seems right to me. Getting a $p^9$ doesn't make any sense whatsoever
